# Who was the swordsman who killed this character in "Akame ga Kill!"?

Tags: manga, akame-ga-kill

As an big fan of *Akame ga Kill!*, I'm sad that my favorite character

> Lubbock

died after fighting with Syura, but when I was reading the manga I noticed that a different character killed them.

This person appears to be a samurai-looking guy with white eyes and a ponytail; he holds a katana and is dressed in a cloak.

> [image: A frowning ronin in a cloak slices through the hand and shoulder of a man with his back to the viewer.]

Does anyone know who he is?

Comment: Heh.  Looks like Ogami Ittō.

Comment: @DavidW I think our edits clashed there; I've added back in the spoiler tags. I don't think it's fair to give away major character deaths so openly.

Comment: @F1Krazy Fair enough, I wasn't trying to roll your change back.  Like you say, I think our edits simply clashed.

Answer (score 2):

This character is [Izou](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Izou), a member of Wild Hunt and a goon of Syura in the manga.

> Izou is a calm, stoic man with an immense blood lust. He claims that
> he needs to allow Kotetsu to "drink blood" regularly. He loves the
> Empire for allowing him to have as many fights as he wants. Unlike the
> rest of his fellow Wild Hunt members, he does not have an obsession
> towards sexual abuse or sexual vices. He is also shown to honor foes
> that he's faced with a strong will, such as Lubbock.

[image]